# Neither pause nor stop works while streaming RTSP with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, live-streaming

I am facing a weird bug on Samsung Devices that, when streaming RTSP using `MediaPlayer`, neither `pause()` nor `stop()` works, but it works well on Nexus S and Nexus 4 when I want to stop streaming.

When I change the link to another live streaming URL, `pause()` and `stop()` work on all devices; but when I use my RTSP URL, `pause()` and `stop()` don't work and logcat doesn't show any error, just "pause JNI pause stop JNI stop"

Anyone facing the same problem? Is it possible that the RTSP link doesn't respond to the pause and stop methods, because other live streaming links work with the same code!